# undefined method `check_delivery_params' for #<Mailgunner::DeliveryMethod:0x00

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, mailgun

> > I deployed a rails 5 app to heroku. I used mailgun for sending emails and it works well in development. In production when I try to sign up a user, I get this error:

[image]

production.rb:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://myappname.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'https'}
 config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
  domain: ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'],
  api_key: ENV['MAILGUN_KEY']
 }
```

The MAILGUN_DOMAIN and MAILGUN_KEY were stored as environment variables in my PC. Is there something I did not do right? Thanks!

After installing figaro gem:

application.yml

```
development:
 MAILGUN_DOMAIN: ******************************
 MAILGUN_KEY: **************************

production:
 MAILGUN_DOMAIN: ******************************
 MAILGUN_KEY: **************************

I still get the same error!!
```

Comment: Are you using the figaro gem?

Comment: no it is mailgunner

Comment: Add `require 'mailgunner'`

Comment: to what file pls?

Comment: also am i supposed to use a gem like figaro or dotenv?

Comment: I added "require mailgunner" in environment.rb but i still got the same error

Comment: i have installed figaro gem, check the update above

Comment: @JohnnyDevv Can you accept or respond to the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is related to the version of the mail gem that is installed as per [this issue on mailgunner](https://github.com/timcraft/mailgunner/issues/13).

The workaround suggested there is to explicitly add the mail gem to your Gemfile and to lock the version to 2.6.5.

```
gem 'mail', '2.6.5'
```

You'll then need to run `bundle update mail --conservative` to get the new version.